# Space Shuttle related quote referring to a bird on the back of a giant bird

Tags: story-identification, arthur-c-clarke

As I look at this [amazing picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAUfI.jpg)  of the [last flight related to the space shuttle](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap120419.html) taken by Ben Cooper, I am trying to recollect a line from some book (Science or Science fiction) that I read a long time back. It described space flight being imagined as a "Bird on the back of another Giant Bird", or some such words...

Does anyone here recollect the book, author, exact line?
I think it was Arthur C. Clarke but I am not sure and can't find the reference with what I remember.

There are strong connotations to the Virgin Atlantic take-off technique as that line described the idea of taking off from a higher altitude (if my memory serves).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Located in **2001: A Space Odyssey** by **Arthur C. Clarke**
Chapter 7: Space Flight,
Dr. Heywood Floyd recalls a quotation of Leonardo da Vinci's displayed in a NASA office once,

> The Great Bird will take its flight on the back of the great bird,
>   bringing glory to the nest where it was born

Referencing Leonardo da Vinci's [Codex on the flight of birds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_on_the_Flight_of_Birds),

> The great bird will take its first flight from the back of [Monte Cecero](http://brunelleschi.imss.fi.it/itineraries/itinerary/TheFlorentineHills.html),
>   filling the universe with stupor, filling all writings with its fame and
>   bringing glory to the nest in which it was born

Other references,

1. Yale University, [Leonardo and the Science of Bird Flight (PDF)](http://www.yale.edu/eeb/prum/pdf/Prum_2008_Leonardo.pdf)
2. [Decoding da Vinci](http://archive.audubonmagazine.org/webexclusives/davincibirds-webexclusives.html)

   - Drawings from the Biblioteca Real in Turin
     (featuring the Codex on the Flight of Birds and 11 drawings by the artist)